# What are the VMware's vm.scoreboard files?

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, vmware-workstation, file-extension

Basically the same ask as [from here](https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Workstation-Pro/VMware-Workstation-16-2-0-and-scoreboard-files-What-it-is/m-p/2872645):

I see a few new files beside usual guest file:

```
vm.scoreboard
vm-1.scoreboard
vm-2.scoreboard
```

etc. What are they?

The answer there doesn't make sense to me:

> Scoreboard:
>
> vmware zero   competition 1

and the only hits I can find is the above question, and [this one (VMware's Scoreboard Widget)](https://docs.vmware.com/en/vRealize-Operations-Manager/8.4/com.vmware.vcom.core.doc/GUID-464C4018-FFD3-4D4A-8D6F-EF70C9572289.html), which I believe to be irrelevant after inspection.

So anyone can help pls? I just started using my vm, and I'm already have 5 of them now (8K each). Can I just keep the last one?

It is created by VMware Workstation **16.2.0+**. Is it specifically for Windows 10 GUEST?

I'm using VMware-Workstation v16.2.0-18760230.x86_64 under Ubuntu 21.10.

Comment: The answer from the VMware Community Forums question was clearly meant to be a joke.  I don't have VMware Workstation 16.2 installed; what the contents of the files?  Are they binary or text-based?

Comment: The files are binary, empty in a Linux machine, mostly empty in a Windows machine. They are meant to be used with a dashboard app that the user develops in some way. I posted this in my answer here.

Comment: @John What answer?

Comment: My answer below was not deemed helpful so it is was deleted.

Comment: @xpt I also replied to your question on forum. it's VMWare 0 , Competitors : 2

Comment: by the way, I run ubuntu as guest OS and I also have those files. it's really a score board because on ma machine it gives the same score. VMWare 0, Competitors 2.  hehe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scoreboard files contain performance information about the VM for the [Scoreboard Widget](https://docs.vmware.com/en/vRealize-Operations/8.10/com.vmware.vcom.core.doc/GUID-464C4018-FFD3-4D4A-8D6F-EF70C9572289.html) and is not required to run the VM. It's mainly used for optimization and troubleshooting purposes.

To disable the scoreboard files, add this line to the VMX file of the VM:

```
vmx.scoreboard.enabled = "FALSE"
```

[Additional resource](https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Workstation-Pro/VMware-Workstation-16-2-0-and-scoreboard-files-What-it-is/td-p/2872645)